# Statements in scala class

Tags: scala

Besides methods and fields, you are allowed to directly put a statement inside a scala class like the following:

```
class printHelloWorld {
  val x = 1
  println("Hello World")
  val y = 2
}

object callHelloWrold extends App {
  val helloWorldObj = new printHelloWorld
}
```

"Hello World" is printed when a new object is created. What is this kind of statement called in scala? Is this statement called after the class constructor and `val x = 1`, but before `val y = 2`? If so, how does the compiler manage to do that? Does it create an anonymous method that encloses all these statements?

Comment: Not quite "an anonymous method", but close. It's the constructor of the class.

Comment: I found an article on http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-four-classes-and-constructors/, it seems the whole class body is called the primary constructor of the class. But if you define a method in the class body, does it also get to included in the primary constructor?

Comment: Yes, everything is constructed with every instantiation. If you have member data/methods that should be "static" then they should go in the class's companion object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of x, the println, and the definition of y are all statements in the primary constructor of the class you're defining. x and y are member variables that can be accessed on the new object that's created. See the below repl session for some examples of interleaving def's, val's, and printlns

```
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 1.0.0-RC7
(Scala 2.12.2 Java 1.8.0_77)
If you like Ammonite, please support our development at www.patreon.com/lihaoyi
mshelton-mshelton@ class Test {
                   val x = 1
                   def a = 5
                   println("defs and vals and constructors and oh my")
                   val z = 3
                   def g(): Unit = {println("sup")}
                   }
defined class Test
mshelton-mshelton@ val test = new Test()
defs and vals and constructors and oh my
test: Test = ammonite.$sess.cmd0$Test@743d0d44
mshelton-mshelton@ test.g()
sup

mshelton-mshelton@ test.a
res3: Int = 5
mshelton-mshelton@ test.x
res4: Int = 1
mshelton-mshelton@
```

Comment: If you define some methods between the line of val x and the line of val y, are they also included in the primary constructors? Or the compiler would just pick out those lines and put them in the constructor and leaves the methods in the class.

Comment: Updated my answer, please see above.